# Can I pull the next element from within a Perl foreach loop?

Tags: perl, loops, foreach

Can I do something like the following in Perl?

```
foreach (@tokens) {
     if (/foo/){
       # simple case, I can act on the current token alone
       # do something
       next;
    }
    if (/bar/) {
       # now I need the next token, too
       # I want to read/consume it, advancing the iterator, so that
       # the next loop iteration will not also see it
       my $nextToken = .....
       # do something
       next;
    }

}
```

**Update:** I need this in Perl, but for curiosity's sake: Do other languages have a neat syntax for that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Must you use a `for` loop? Copy the original and 'consume' it with [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @original = 'a' .. 'z';    # Original
my @array = @original;        # Copy

while (my $token = shift @array) {

    shift @array if $token =~ /[nr]/; # consumes the next element
    print $token;
}

# prints 'abcdefghijklmnpqrtuvwxyz' ('s' and 'o' are missing)
```

Comment: Nice. In my case, destroying original is not even a problem, so I can do without the copy.

Answer (score 10):

Not with a `foreach` loop.  You can use a C-style `for` loop:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#tokens; ++$i) {
  local $_ = $tokens[$i];
  if (/foo/){
     next;
  }
  if (/bar/) {
    my $nextToken = $tokens[++$i];
    # do something
    next;
  }
}
```

You could also use something like [Array::Iterator](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Array::Iterator).  I'll leave that version as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Answer (score 9):

Starting with Perl 5.12, [each is now more flexible](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5120delta.html#each-is-now-more-flexible) by also working on arrays:

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

my @tokens = 'a' .. 'z';

while (my ($i, $val) = each @tokens) {
    if ($val =~ m/[aeiou]/) {
        ($i, $val) = each @tokens;   # get next token after a vowel
        print $val;
    }
}

# => bfjpv
```

One caveat with [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html), remember the iterator is global and is not reset if you break out of a loop.

For eg:

```
while (my ($i, $val) = each @tokens) {
    print $val;
    last if $i == 12;
}

# => abcdefghijklm

my ($i, $val) = each @tokens;
say "Now at => $val ($i)";         # Now at => n (13)
```

So use [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) or [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) to manually reset the iterator:

```
keys @tokens;                      # resets iterator
($i, $val) = each @tokens;
say "Now at => $val ($i)";         # Now at => a (0)
```

Comment: Whoa!  I didn't know -- this will come  handy.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    my $arr = [0..9];

    foreach ( 1 ..  scalar @{$arr} ) {

           my $curr = shift @{$arr};

           my $next = shift @{$arr};

           unshift @{$arr} , $next;

           print "CURRENT :: $curr :: NEXT :: $next \n";
    }
```

Comment: Best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I like Zaids answer but it fails if it encounters a nul element in the array
so...

```
while (@array) {

    my $token = shift @array;
    shift @array if $token =~ /[nr]/; # consumes the next element
    print $token;
}
```

this will not stop until `@array` is empty.